# Как реализовать вывод лога в listBox? WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ооп, listbox

у меня в одном решении есть Form1.cs и класс test.cs, в Form1 есть listBox(в моем проекте называется LogBox), сюда данные должны передаваться при выполнении метода test.cs, который вызывается в Form1.cs при клике по кнопке, но у меня никак не получается передать данные из test.cs, поскольку этот класс не видит listBox.

Я пытаюсь реализовать лог, когда в процессе выполнения различных методов, которые вызываются кликом по кнопке, в лог выводится информация о каждом шаге, который выполняется внутри вызванного метода, например, построчно выводится информация о том, какой файл копируется в данный момент и т.п.

Возможно, подобные логи формируются каким-то другим способом, возможно даже есть специальные команды для этого, но мне о таких не известно.

На данный момент реализовал вывод в лог только информацию о начале выполнения вызванного метода, и о его завершении, поскольку все это реализуется в рамках Form1, который видит мой listBox и проблем с выводом информации тут нет.

В данный момент это выглядит в Form1.cs примерно вот так:

```
private void ButtonApel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            LogBox.AppendText($"{dateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}\t Начинаю копировать файлы..." + Environment.NewLine);
 
            Apel_check apel_count = new Apel_check();
            int total_apel = 0;
            apel_count.Unloading_ZRD(out total_apel);
 
            dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            LogBox.AppendText($"{dateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}\t Готово. Скопировал профили с апелляциями: {total_apel} шт." + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

Внутри этого метода Unloading_ZRD происходит поиск и копирование файлов, вот эту информацию пошагово в лог уже не получается вывести.

Comment: `LogBox.Items.Add(ваш элемент)`

Comment: Вы ListBox и TextBox не перепутали случаем?